UserForm Error: Run-Time Error 5 (Invalid Procedure Call or Argument)
UserForm UI
I have created an Inventory Management System for my company, using an Excel UserForm.
It is supposed to take the following inputs:
Product Type: Dropdown
Product Name: Dropdown
Date of Storage: Text Box
Sourced From: Dropdown
Stored In: Dropdown
Label: Text Box
Storage Location: Dropdown
Weight: Text Box
These are columns 1 to 8 in a subsheet Data_Entries. There are 35 further columns in the subsheet, that I together call GLC_Headers (since they give data on chromatography for each product).
My userform has to dynamically show the relevant data headers out of the 35 and populate them, based on the Product Type. The relevant data headers have been stored in another hidden subsheet GLC_Headers for the code to refer to.
The UserForm needs to have the functionalities of adding an entry, modifying and deleting the entry (the row will be found by Label value). The modification, deletion history is saved to a History_Values Sheet.
I have attached an image of the userform layout for your reference, and here is the code:
UserForm Code:
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Initialize ComboBoxes
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Entries")
    Call PopulateComboBox(Me.cboSourcedFrom, wsData.Columns(4))
    Call PopulateComboBox(Me.cboStoredIn, wsData.Columns(5))
    Call PopulateComboBox(Me.cboProductName, wsData.Columns(2))
    Call PopulateComboBox(Me.cboProductType, wsData.Columns(1))
    Call PopulateComboBox(Me.cboStorageLocation, wsData.Columns(7))
    
    Debug.Print ("Initializing....")

    ' Populate GLC Headers
    Dim glcHeaders As Collection
    Set glcHeaders = GetGLCHeaders
    Call PopulateGLCFrame(glcHeaders)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveEntry_Click()
    ' Validate Form Data
    If Not ValidateFormData(Me) Then
        MsgBox "Please fill all required fields before saving!", vbExclamation, "Validation Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Save Data
    
    If ValidateFormData(Me) Then
        Call SaveEntry(Me)
    End If
    
    ' Confirmation
    MsgBox "Entry Saved Successfully!", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateGLCFrame(headers As Collection)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim currentRow As Integer
    Dim ctrlTop As Single
    Dim ctrlLeft As Single
    Dim lbl As Control
    Dim txt As Control
    
    ' Clear existing controls in the frame
    For Each ctrl In Me.fraGLCValues.Controls
        Me.fraGLCValues.Controls.Remove ctrl.Name
    Next ctrl

    ' Dimensions and settings
    Dim columnWidth As Single: columnWidth = 150
    Dim rowHeight As Single: rowHeight = 20
    Dim fontSize As Single: fontSize = 8
    Dim maxRowsPerColumn As Integer: maxRowsPerColumn = 12

    ' Initialize column and row trackers
    currentColumn = 0
    currentRow = 0
    
    ' Loop through headers and add controls dynamically
    For i = 1 To headers.Count
        ' Calculate position
        ctrlTop = currentRow * rowHeight
        ctrlLeft = currentColumn * columnWidth

        ' Add Label
        Set lbl = Me.fraGLCValues.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblGLC_" & i)
        lbl.Caption = headers(i)
        lbl.Left = ctrlLeft
        lbl.Top = ctrlTop
        lbl.Width = 75
        lbl.Height = rowHeight
        lbl.Font.Size = fontSize

        ' Add TextBox
        Set txt = Me.fraGLCValues.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "txtGLC_" & headers(i))
        txt.Left = ctrlLeft + 75
        txt.Top = ctrlTop
        txt.Width = 75
        txt.Height = rowHeight
        txt.Font.Size = fontSize

        ' Update row/column trackers
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        If currentRow >= maxRowsPerColumn Then
            currentRow = 0
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub btnDeleteEntry_Click()
    Call DeleteEntry(Me)
End Sub
Private Sub btnModifyEntry_Click()
    Call ModifyEntry(Me)
End Sub

Helper Module Code:
Sub PopulateComboBox(cbo As ComboBox, rng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And Not dict.exists(cell.Value) Then
            dict.Add cell.Value, Nothing
            cbo.AddItem cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Function GetGLCHeaders() As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim headers As Collection
    Dim cell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GLC_Headers")
    Set headers = New Collection

    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then headers.Add cell.Value
    Next cell

    Set GetGLCHeaders = headers
End Function

Function ValidateFormData(frmInventory As Object) As Boolean
    ValidateFormData = True

    ' Validate required fields
    If frmInventory.cboProductType.Value = "" Then ValidateFormData = False
    If frmInventory.cboProductName.Value = "" Then ValidateFormData = False
    If frmInventory.txtDateOfStorage.Value = "" Then ValidateFormData = False
    If frmInventory.cboSourcedFrom.Value = "" Then ValidateFormData = False
    If frmInventory.cboStoredIn.Value = "" Then ValidateFormData = False
    If frmInventory.txtLabel.Value = "" Then ValidateFormData = False
    If frmInventory.cboStorageLocation.Value = "" Then ValidateFormData = False
    If frmInventory.txtWeight.Value = "" Then ValidateFormData = False

    ' Show error message if validation fails
    If Not ValidateFormData Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all required fields before proceeding.", vbExclamation, "Validation Error"
    End If
End Function


Sub SaveEntry(frmInventory As Object)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newRow As Long
    
    ' Set the Data_Entries worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Entries")
    
    ' Find the next available row
    newRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Add data to the worksheet
    ws.Cells(newRow, 1).Value = frmInventory.cboProductType.Value ' Product Type
    ws.Cells(newRow, 2).Value = frmInventory.cboProductName.Value ' Product Name
    ws.Cells(newRow, 3).Value = Format(frmInventory.txtDateOfStorage.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY") ' Date of Storage
    ws.Cells(newRow, 4).Value = frmInventory.cboSourcedFrom.Value ' Sourced From
    ws.Cells(newRow, 5).Value = frmInventory.cboStoredIn.Value ' Stored In
    ws.Cells(newRow, 6).Value = frmInventory.txtLabel.Value ' Label
    ws.Cells(newRow, 7).Value = frmInventory.cboStorageLocation.Value ' Storage Location
    ws.Cells(newRow, 8).Value = frmInventory.txtWeight.Value ' Weight

    ' Add GLC values dynamically
    Dim header As Range, i As Integer
    i = 9 ' Start column for GLC headers
    For Each header In ws.Rows(1).Cells
        If header.Value <> "" And Not IsEmpty(frmInventory.Controls("txtGLC_" & header.Value)) Then
            ws.Cells(newRow, i).Value = frmInventory.Controls("txtGLC_" & header.Value).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next header

    ' Confirmation message
    MsgBox "Entry added successfully!", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub



Sub LogHistory(actionType As String, originalData As Variant)
    Dim wsHistory As Worksheet
    Dim newRow As Long

    ' Create History_Entries sheet if it doesn't exist
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsHistory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("History_Entries")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsHistory Is Nothing Then
        Set wsHistory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        wsHistory.Name = "History_Entries"
        wsHistory.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Timestamp"
        wsHistory.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Action"
        wsHistory.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Original Data"
    End If

    ' Determine next empty row
    newRow = wsHistory.Cells(wsHistory.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' Log the action
    With wsHistory
        .Cells(newRow, 1).Value = Now ' Current timestamp
        .Cells(newRow, 2).Value = actionType
        .Cells(newRow, 3).Value = Join(originalData, ", ") ' Combine original data into one cell
    End With
End Sub

Sub ModifyEntry(frmInventory As Object)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, historyWs As Worksheet
    Dim labelToFind As String
    Dim foundRow As Long
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim header As Range
    
    ' Set the Data_Entries and History worksheets
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Entries")
    Set historyWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("History_Entries")
    
    ' Get the label to search for
    labelToFind = InputBox("Please enter the label of the entry to modify:", "Enter Label")
    
    ' Find the row with the matching label
    On Error Resume Next
    foundRow = Application.Match(labelToFind, ws.Range("F:F"), 0) ' Assuming 'Label' is in column F
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If foundRow = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Label not found in the database.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Save the original data to the history sheet
    newRow = historyWs.Cells(historyWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For i = 1 To ws.Columns.Count
        historyWs.Cells(newRow, i).Value = ws.Cells(foundRow, i).Value
    Next i
    
    ' Update the data in the Data_Entries sheet
    ws.Cells(foundRow, 1).Value = frmInventory.cboProductType.Value ' Product Type
    ws.Cells(foundRow, 2).Value = frmInventory.cboProductName.Value ' Product Name
    ws.Cells(foundRow, 3).Value = Format(frmInventory.txtDateOfStorage.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY") ' Date of Storage
    ws.Cells(foundRow, 4).Value = frmInventory.cboSourcedFrom.Value ' Sourced From
    ws.Cells(foundRow, 5).Value = frmInventory.cboStoredIn.Value ' Stored In
    ws.Cells(foundRow, 6).Value = frmInventory.txtLabel.Value ' Label
    ws.Cells(foundRow, 7).Value = frmInventory.cboStorageLocation.Value ' Storage Location
    ws.Cells(foundRow, 8).Value = frmInventory.txtWeight.Value ' Weight

    ' Update GLC values dynamically
    i = 9 ' Start column for GLC headers
    For Each header In ws.Rows(1).Cells
        If header.Value <> "" And Not IsEmpty(frmInventory.Controls("txtGLC_" & header.Value)) Then
            ws.Cells(foundRow, i).Value = frmInventory.Controls("txtGLC_" & header.Value).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next header
    
    ' Confirmation message
    MsgBox "Entry modified successfully!", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

Sub DeleteEntry(frmInventory As Object)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, historyWs As Worksheet
    Dim labelToFind As String
    Dim foundRow As Long
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Set the Data_Entries and History worksheets
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Entries")
    Set historyWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("History_Entries")
    
    ' Get the label to search for
    labelToFind = InputBox("Please enter the label of the entry to modify:", "Enter Label")
    
    ' Find the row with the matching label
    On Error Resume Next
    foundRow = Application.Match(labelToFind, ws.Range("F:F"), 0) ' Assuming 'Label' is in column F
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If foundRow = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Label not found in the database.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Save the original data to the history sheet
    newRow = historyWs.Cells(historyWs.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For i = 1 To ws.Columns.Count
        historyWs.Cells(newRow, i).Value = ws.Cells(foundRow, i).Value
    Next i
    
    ' Delete the row from the Data_Entries sheet
    ws.Rows(foundRow).Delete
    
    ' Confirmation message
    MsgBox "Entry deleted successfully!", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

I tried running the UserForm on VBA using frmInventory.Show, but it showed Error 5: (Runtime Error): Invalid Procedure Call or Argument.
I am unable to find the error. The form is not running from a button either, that is linked to a function that refers frmInventory.Show
Please help me fix this and understand how I can refine my code for the next time, since I am a beginner at VBA.

Which code line causes the error?

In PopulateComboBox add  .Cells to rng ie  For Each cell In rng.Cells. Also I suggest you reduce the ranges from wsData.Columns(4) to rngData.Columns(4) where Set rngData = wsData.UsedRange

@Shrotter it does not show which code line causes the error. I also ran Debug--> Compile, and it gives no result, doesn't stop executing.
